# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I have a method,

```
public static DateTime ToDate(this object value)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(value.ToString(), "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

When i run this code with this code,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToDate().ToString());
}
```

And there is a error on program like this,

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
```

How can i solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Posted code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Obviously "dd.MM.yyyy" is not a valid format.

Comment: Does it really make sense to convert _any object_ to a date?  That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Your extension method shouldn't accept a parameter with a type of object. It should accept a string. And you should probably provide an overloaded version of this extension method so that you can specify the format, rather than embedding it in the method body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that your extension method tries to parse the string specifically in the `dd.MM.yyyy` format. And you're testing your extension method using the `DateTime.Now` which returns a `DateTime` in a format of a current culture on your machine (including hours, minutes, etc.), which may may not be in a `dd.MM.yyyy` format.  You can test your extension method as follows: `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy").ToDate()`

However, If I understand correctly what you're trying to do it is better to change the extension method as follows.

```
public static DateTime ToDate(this string value, string format)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(value, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

and use it as follows

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Testing the extension method.
    MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy").ToDate("dd.MM.yyyy").ToString());
}
```

Or, if you specifically receive a `DateTime` in `dd.MM.yyyy` because of the localization it is better to set the culture of your application globally like so.

```
// Substitute appropriate culture.
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture  = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
```

That way you will not need your extension method since the `DateTime` will always be in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to  use the [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx)

Then you  choose the date format that you need

For example :

```
public static DateTime ToDate(this object value)
{
    DateTime OutputDate ;
    DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out OutputDate);
    return OutputDate ?? DateTime.Now  ;
}
```

In the example : the format is "dd.MM.yyyy" and the input date string is `value`. The `OutputDate` will take as value the new datetime object and if the instruction fails it will take null.

Please, verify the format of the date and replace it in the example above if you need

Comment: This code wont compile, `DateTime` is a value type, it can't be null

Answer (score 0):

your first function must be as follow :

```
public static DateTime ToDate(this object value)
{
     string date = value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
     DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date); 
     return dt;
}
```